# How can i avoid from single quotes in message, when message is in a russian unicode?

Tags: java, selenium, unicode, tinymce

I start Selenium Webdriver and launch following code

```
body1.sendKeys("'\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\'");
```

I got message with single quotes, if i set this code without quotes, it isn't displayed in Tinymce. Is some solution to fix this problem?

Comment: then just use the quotes, where is the problem?

Comment: @Thariama It isn't problem at all. But i can manually type some message in russian  in tinymce by buttons and it is displayed without quotes :). So i guess, there is some possibility to use automation for that.

Comment: In -> `body1.sendKeys("'\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\'");` The last \ is an error ? You're using \' maybe you're scaping that single quote, or not escaping the first one...

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the message you call

```
message = message.substring(1, message.length-1);
```

Comment: It isn't solution..Because quotes are deleted, the message isn't displayed in Tinymce, i wrote it before.